# Google Drive: How to copy shared folder content to another folder?

Tags: backup, sync, google-drive, google-search

I have access to a folder shared with me (let's say SharedWithMe folder) and I want to backup this folder as the sharing will be end in the future. So, is it possible to sync / copy the SharedWithMe folder content with / to another folder (let's say MyBackup) in y Google Drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not copy shared folders directly, as of yet. For this purpose you'll need to use Google Colaboratory:

1. [Create a new Notebook on Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/#create=true)
2. First You'll need to mount your drive as so:

```python
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
```

This asks for a authorisation code. 
3. Now, on a separate tab, open your [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) and go to *Shared with Me*. Right click and click  *'Add Shortcut to Drive'*. This shortcut is temporary and can be deleted later. 
4. Type `%cd /gdrive/MyDrive/<path-to-the-shortcut>` to go to that location and then type `pwd` to get the path. 
5. Execute `!cp -r 'above-path/.' '/gdrive/My Drive/<destinantion>'`

OR you can avoid all that and simply execute this:

```python
#@title Deeply copy shared folders in Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
import os

print('Mounting Google Drive...')
drive.mount('/gdrive')

src_path = '/gdrive/MyDrive/DE A1' #@param {type: 'string'}
assert os.path.exists(src_path), f"Source '{src_path}' doesn't exist!"

target_path = '/gdrive/MyDrive/Language/German' #@param {type: 'string'}
os.makedirs(target_path, exist_ok=True)
assert os.path.exists(target_path), f"Target '{target_path}' doesn't exist!"

target_path = os.path.join(target_path, os.path.basename(src_path))
print(f'Copying from "{src_path}" to "{target_path}"...')
os.makedirs(target_path, exist_ok=True)
!cp -rf "$src_path"/* "$target_path"  # also work when source is a shortcut
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this wonderful explanations, voted up. On the other hand, I have some questions related to this steps >

Comment: **1.** Does this script runs periodically or manually?

Comment: **2.** As far as I see, this script copies shared folder to one of my Google Drive folder. So, what if I need to synch my folder and copy again the same shared folder to the same destination? In this case will it overwrite  the files that has already been copied before?

Comment: By the way I cannot vote up as I have not enough reputation. So, could you pls vote up the question?

Comment: This method, as you've said, just copies the files onto your drive, **just once**. So, nothing like syncing can be done, unfortunately. I *think* that online service like **Multicloud** have some features that might help you do that, but I've never used that myself, so I'm uncertain. Moreover such services are paid, so you should run the program time and again manually unless you have some serious work.

Comment: And yes, it will overwrite the previous files.

Comment: BTW if my answer worked for you, you can accept my answer by pressing the grey tick below the downvote button

Comment: Of course I will select it as answer after I evaluate the code successfully. I would never vote down such kind of nice effort and help, contrary I always try to vote up in addition to marking as answer ;)

Comment: I tried to follow the steps, but I think I am lost. So, just concentrating the last part (execution script), which part should I change with my source and destination, etc.? Because the link format that I copied (shared folder) is different than the example. So, could you pls. emphasize the parts that to be changed according to my situation? Assume that shared folder is **SharedWithMe** folder and I will copy it **MyBackup** folder in My Drive folder in drive?

Comment: First of all you need to create shortcut, as told earlier. Lets say, you made the shortcut in the main folder — MyDrive. So now the src_path will be `/gdrive/MyDrive/SharedWithMe` and target path will be `/gdrive/MyDrive/MyBackup`

Comment: And you need not change anything in the script. As soon as you'll paste it into colab notebook, it will automatically ask you for input. Paste it there

Comment: It seems to be perfectly working, thanks a lot. Just a question: I think it behaves exactly similar to copying files on Windows.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You got it right

Answer (score 0):

The said method from @Saaransh_Garg seems not working now on some sub-folders that is also shared.

However it is still possible to copy a shared file if the path is provided, so instead of relying on the native system call to recursively copy files, following script, which is also supposed to run in colab notebook, list all the files and folders and copy using `shutil`

```
from google.colab import drive
import os
import shutil

print('Mounting Google Drive...')
drive.mount('/gdrive')

# List all dirs and sub-dirs
# OS method won't work on links 
def walk_and_copy(root_path, parent_path, target_path, max_depth=3):
    dirs = 0
    copied = 0
    failed = 0
    if max_depth == 0: return (0,0,0)

    print(f"Listing: {root_path}")
    for entry in os.scandir(parent_path):
        subpath = entry.path[len(root_path)+1:]
        target_p = os.path.join(target_path, subpath)

        # DFS
        if entry.is_dir():
           dirs += 1
           os.makedirs(target_p, exist_ok=True)
           d,c,f = walk_and_copy(root_path, entry.path, target_path, max_depth-1)
           dirs += d
           copied += c
           failed += f
        else:
           print(f"copying to {target_p}")
           try:
               shutil.copyfile(entry.path, target_p)
               copied += 1
           except Exception as e:
               print(f"Cannot copy {target_p}, {type(e)}")
               failed += 1
               return (dirs, copied, failed)

src_path = "/gdrive/MyDrive/src_path" #@param {type: 'string'}
assert os.path.exists(src_path), f"Source '{src_path}' doesn't exist!"

target_path = '/gdrive/MyDrive/target_path' #@param {type: 'string'}
os.makedirs(target_path, exist_ok=True) 
assert os.path.exists(target_path), f"Target '{target_path}' doesn't exist!"

target_path = os.path.join(target_path, os.path.basename(src_path))
d, c, f = walk_and_copy(src_path, src_path, target_path, -1)
print(f"dirs listed: {d}, copied files: {c}, failed: {f}")
```